# How to disable the Visual Basic dialog when double click the ActiveX Control

Tags: c++, com, ms-office, activex

I developed a custom ActiveX control:ax_love.

When I insert it into a ppt inside and double click this control will show a pop-up VisualBasic window,this is unacceptable. I hope the double click action will trigger my own function.

ps:I use atl/com in vs2017.

[image]

Comment: You are in design mode.

Comment: I think the VBA tag is not relefant to your question - better to remove it. The only discussions I can remember seeing even close to this are very old threads in the VSTO forum on msdn, from the time the MS people were supporting their new technology. At the time, they also handled general Office-related dev topics, including creating Active X controls for working on the document surface. None, however, were powerpoint-related, as I recall, mostly Word. But some of the info may help you...

Comment: @Cindy Meister ,I try to search in msdn  but find nothing.When users use our software they will feel confused,they do not konw vb.

Comment: Here's one discussion from that forum that's probably relevant: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71a75dc4-dcea-454a-9e4a-011a2f811994/vsto-activex-and-powerpoint?forum=vsto I recall others, but didn't turn up anything else useful in a quick forum search.

Comment: I do understand your concern about your users and seeing such a dialog. It's just that the "vba" tag will not bring this to the attention of people who can help you. It is quite likely that the double-click is putting PowerPoint into developer Design mode, as another comment mentioned, but it's no possible to be sure without seeing a picture or knowing more about the dialog box. Adding a screen shot of the dialog box might help clarify what's happening.

Comment: @ACatInLove is correct. What you are describing in normal behavior from ActiveX controls when in design mode (i.e. designing the presentation).  In Excel, you can toggle design mode on/off while working on the worksheet, but in PowerPoint you either have design mode or run mode (i.e.: run the presentation).  It does not matter whether you wrote the ActiveX control or you inserted one from the Developer tab on the ribbon.  That is the way it is.

Comment: @ACatInLove ，You're right,I understand the wrong way,@Cindy Meister I added a screen shot picture

Answer (score 5):

In Design mode, clicking on an ActiveX control will open up the VB window - this is as-expected. In Presentation mode, clicking on the ActiveX control will trigger your function.
If you want a version of this to only open in Presentation mode (so users won't be taken to a VB page), save the file as a **PowerPoint Macro-Enabled Show** (.ppsm). Then it always opens in Presentation mode (keep a copy in .pptm format for editing, but don't give that one to your users).

Comment: @Aliceljm, this seems to be a correct answer, any update on this?

Comment: @tysonwright,I tried the method you said, this method doesn't solve my problem, what I need is a code level solution such as disable vb dialog or set a custom double-click callback function. I still thank you for your answer.